# Search for a value in a list in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm using Python to search for the position of an entered name in a list. I use the binary search: compare entered name with the middle-value of the list, if not matched, search in the 1st half list then 2nd half list. 
When I run following script, IDE shows nothing. Please help me review it:

```
def search_for_name(name, list):
  midValue = list[int(len(list)/2)]
  x = 0
  if name == midValue:
    x = int(len(list)/2)
    return x
  elif name < midValue:
    while x < int(len(list))/2:
      if list[x] == name:
        return x
      else:
        x += 1
  else:
    x = int(len(list)/2)
    while x <= int(len(list)):
      if list[x] == name:
        return x
      else:
        x += 1
  print('The name you want to search exists in our list. Its position is {}'.format(x))
```

Comment: Where do you actually use your `search_for_name` function?

Comment: Why would it show anything? It's just a function definition.

Comment: Is your list ordered? If not, a binary search doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: But it contains a print. @HeapOverflow

Comment: just use list.find('name to be searched') it give the index position

Comment: @Hari: That's `O(n)`; proper binary search is `O(log n)` (though this implementation isn't binary search, it's just splitting the linear search in half once).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Nah, it's O(1), thanks to `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Comment: @HeapOverflow: True. `index` then.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the found value from the function, which means that your `print` statement will never be called. Instead, use the value returned and then print that:

```
def search_for_name(name, list):
    ...

pos = search_for_name('matt', ['a', 'b', 'matt', 'x', 'y', 'z'])

if pos is None:
    print("Name was not found")
else:
    print('The name you want to search exists in our list. Its position is {}'.format(pos))
```

Comment: `f"Its position is {pos}."`

Comment: As long as you're on 3.6, definitely!